# MySQL query to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a table with the columns `id` , `seq_id` , `tran_date`.

**Sample Data:**

```
id     | seq_id | tran_date
------ | ------   --------
1      |  1     |  2016-11-01
1      |  2     |  2016-11-01
1      |  1     |  2016-11-02
1      |  2     |  2016-11-02
1      |  1     |  2016-11-12
1      |  2     |  2016-11-12
```

my expected result is

```
1      |  2     |  2016-11-02
```

**Condition**:

`tran_date` should be less than today (2016-11-08) and max(seq_id) record should be listed.

how to implement the Hibernate Query using criteria api to the above?

Real time MySQL query using now is as below, need to convert the same into Hibernate Criteria:

```
SELECT *
  FROM testtable tt 
  WHERE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(tt.tran_date, '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(tt.seq_id , 2, '0')) =
    (SELECT MAX(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(mtv1.tran_date, '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(mtv1.seq_id , 2, '0')))
    FROM testtable tt1 WHERE tt1.`Label_Id` = tt1.`id` 
    AND mtv1.tran_date<= CURRENT_DATE() GROUP BY mtv.`id`)
```

Comment: There two column with max(seq_id). Which one do you want to get? With max tran_date?

Comment: Ok I realise your sql and saw

Answer (score 0):

You can make your sql query's equivalent with `Hibernate Criteria`.

```
public YourClassName getResult() throws ParseException {
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2016-11-08");
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(YourClassName.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("tran_date", date));
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.max("id"), "id");
    projectionList.add(Projections.max("seq_id"), "seq_id");
    projectionList.add(Projections.max("tran_date"), "tran_date");
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(YourClassName.class));
    if (criteria.list().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        YourClassName yourClassName = (YourClassName) criteria.list().get(0);
        return yourClassName;
    }
}
```

Comment: table has few more columns, If I apply group by id on table i should get max(trans_date,sequence) records..  Where above will fetch 3 max values  records. In Above mentioned SQL query I mentioned * indicating all columns based on three conditions 1) max(trans_date,sequence)  2) trans_date <= current_date(). 3) group by id.

Comment: All records id is 1?

Comment: It varies for Example:   <pre>                                                                                          id     | seq_id | tran_date
------ | ------   --------
1      |  1     |  2016-11-02
1      |  2     |  2016-11-02
1      |  1     |  2016-11-12
1      |  2     |  2016-11-12                                                                             2      |  1     |  2016-11-01
2      |  2     |  2016-11-01
2      |  1     |  2016-11-02
2      |  2     |  2016-11-02
3      |  1     |  2016-11-12
3      |  2     |  2016-11-12 </pre>  I hope now you will understand

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Also sql is not true in my opinion. For solution please give us detailed information in your question.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tran_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `seq_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
insert  into `testtable`(`id`,`tran_date`,`seq_id`,`name`,`type`) values 
(1,'2016-11-01',1,'Thread1','Control'),
(1,'2016-11-01',2,'Thread1 Moved','Pending'),
(1,'2016-11-08',1,'Thread1','Control'),
(2,'2016-11-02',1,'Normal','Control'),
(2,'2016-11-02',2,'Normal','Revised'),
(2,'2016-11-14',2,'Future','Revise Again'),

Comment: (3,'2016-11-08',1,'Future','Revise Again'),
(3,'2016-11-08',2,'Proocess','Completed');

SELECT *
  FROM testtable tt 
  WHERE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(tt.tran_date, '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(tt.seq_id , 2, '0')) =
    (SELECT MAX(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(tt1.tran_date, '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(tt1.seq_id , 2, '0')))
    FROM testtable tt1 WHERE tt.`id` = tt1.`id` 
    AND tt1.tran_date<= CURRENT_DATE() GROUP BY tt.`id`);

Comment: Above I have kept DB table and insert queries with sql select query hope after executing above queries you will understand the requirement

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for your problem.

Comment: Hi,  Afsun Khammadli  Have you found any solution. Thanks for your support

Comment: No. I can not find solution